# In Eclipse, what is 'Enclosing type" when creating a class?

Tags: java, eclipse, inner-classes

In Eclipse, when you are creating a class, there is a checkbox saying 'Enclosing type'. Does anyone know what it does? I have attached the screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add a [nested class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) using `Enclosing type` option

For example Class com.A, Add it as Enclosing type of new Class B

[image: 1]

It will create a nested class B

```
public class A {

    private static class B {

    }

}
```

See more in [Eclipse Help](https://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-wizard-class.htm)

> Enclosing type Select this option to choose a type in which to enclose the new class.

Answer (score 0):

```
So in this case where java file is created inside  the existing java file .like

where we selected the Test1 as Enclosing type and Test2 is the new java class file.


public class Test1 {
public class Test2 {
    }
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("simple its the part of the class Test1");
}
}
```